# Compare 2 textbox values charcter by character

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to comapare two textbox values words by words and check if the words are same or not. If its not same then it should tell me the percentage of matching words.

For example : I am a good boy(text box1) 
Am a god boy (text box 2)

Then the result should be (3/5)*100 as 2 words are not matching that is I and good.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Whts you're code you tried?

Comment: first clear what you have to compare words or char

Comment: @manan5439 words

Comment: it is possible i can write java program for your logic you can use it in android

Comment: @manan5439 yes i can try that.cany you provide me with java code

Answer (score 0):

here is a code as you want

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str1 = "I am a good boy";
  String [] s_str1 = str1.split(" ");
  String str2 = "Am a god boy";
  String [] s_str2 = str2.split(" ");
  int match = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<s_str1.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<s_str2.length;j++){
      if(s_str1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s_str2[j])){
        match++;
      }
    }
  }
  int result = match*100/s_str1.length;           //use length of string which is 
                                                                        your main str

  System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int getCommonWords(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1.split(" ")));
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s2.split(" ")));
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    return set1.size();
}
```

returns the number of common words between 2 strings. It is case-sensitive.